# Order in loop of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I wish show category 35 before 33 on index.php and archive.php. Is that possible?

My code is this:

```
<?php
    if ( in_category( '467' )) {
        echo 'Todas las provincias';
    } else {
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {

            if (($category->cat_ID == '2' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '3' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '5' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '6' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '38' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '39' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '40' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '41' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '42' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '43' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '44' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '45' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '46' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '47' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '48' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '50' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '51' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '52' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '53' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '54' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '55' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '56' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '57' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '58' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '60' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '61' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '62' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '63' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '64' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '65' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '66' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '67' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '68' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '69' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '70' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '71' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '72' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '73' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '74' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '75' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '76' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '77' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '78' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '79' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '80' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '81' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '82' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '83' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '326' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '327' ) || ($category->cat_ID == '335' )) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><span> , </span>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a plugin for this. Try this one for example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/